# no suitable method found for findViewById(FloatingActionButton)

Tags: android

Am trying to build a simple application for fetching Image from URL, via following code, but getting no suitable method found for `findViewById(FloatingActionButton)` error, help would be appreciated.
Most codes are android studio's biolerplate for basic `activity`, but am unable to find malfunctioned code anyway.

```
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;

    import static singh.rahul.com.imagedownloader.R.id.fab;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imgDownloaded;

    public void DownloadImage(View v){
        ImageDownloaderClass task=new ImageDownloaderClass();
        Bitmap myRawImage;
        try{
            myRawImage=task.execute("Any Image URL").get();
            imgDownloaded.setImageBitmap(myRawImage);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public class ImageDownloaderClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls){
            try{
                URL url=new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connections=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connections.connect();
                InputStream is=connections.getInputStream();
                Bitmap theBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                return theBitmap;

            }catch (MalformedURLException mue){
                mue.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        imgDownloaded=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Downloading Image...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                DownloadImage(View);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Looking forward for help !

Comment: `FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(fab);`

Comment: Voted to close `primarily opinion-based`

Comment: Replace
 `FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `fab`

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(fab);
```

You need  to pass the id (from the xml layout):

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.your_fab);
```

Also, inside fab button listener, this line:

```
DownloadImage(View);
```

should be:

```
DownloadImage(view); //lower case
```

Comment: thanks that worked, but another problem occurs, Error:(73, 31) error: cannot find symbol variable View.

Comment: @JamesMacCoy `import android.view.View;`

Comment: Put `DownloadImage(view);` instead of `DownloadImage(View);` (lower case) in the button listener

Comment: i think its  **`DownloadImage(imgDownloaded);`**

Comment: @Prem actually, neither `view` nor `imgDownladed` are needed, since `view` is not used inside the method and `imgDownloaded` is a class field.

Comment: @Héctor agree with u sir

Comment: @JamesMacCoy you should accept this ans like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Answer (score 1):

> findViewById(int id)

This method takes argument as int (id of view).

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.yourId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

Instead of this

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(fab);
```

Hope this will help.